# Building Android project with Gradle failed

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I'm trying from yesterday to configure gradle to build Android project. I've got same error since then:

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+.

The official fix on many sites is to install Android Support Repository. I have it installed already, but problem still occurs. I've run out of ideas what can be wrong here...

Here is full code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
     }

     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5+'
     }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
              manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
              java.srcDirs = ['src']
              resources.srcDirs = ['src']
              aild.srcDirs = ['src']
              renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
              res.srcDirs = ['res']
              assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you located those support jar? They should be under ...sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4

Comment: See if this helps - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h74i7krG33Y . I was able to setup jenkins successfully following the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional block at the top level after your `apply plugin` line:

```
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }
```

In general, you need a `repositories` block at the same level as any `dependencies` block (hence why you also need one in the `buildscript` block).

Most of the time, you'd move your `buildscript` block to the top level `build.gradle` (so that all your modules use the same gradle build) rather than have them both at the module level.

Comment: Have you tried also switching your support version to 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+`? That's the latest version

Comment: Yes, unfortunently result is the same... :/

Comment: You can turn on `--info` or `--debug` logging to see what's going on. Maybe you are behind a proxy, and haven't configured the proxy in Gradle. In that case, all attempts to contact a repository will fail.

Comment: Even though it doesn't solve the author question, it helped me in similar situation... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

See http://tools.android.com/knownissues section Bundled Maven Repository

> To fix this, open the SDK manager, and make sure that the "Android
>   Support Repository" (not just Android Support Library) is installed:

Answer (score 0):

com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+ - this dependency isn't in Maven Central.
Try to use https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to build the Android samples. My problem appeared because the `ANDROID_HOME` was not set correctly.